# LongListSelector and Pull to refresh in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector, pull-to-refresh

I've been browsing for quite a few related questions on SO and did not find a good definitive answer anywhere.

Also this link (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx) did not help either because it's old and things changed a lot since then.

At the same time there are already a lot of applications I've seen that do have this feature. How can I implement it?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Really? I want to add "pull down to refresh" feature to my LongListSelector. I've found no obvious instructions so I want to know the possible approaches to this.

Comment: `LongListSelector` is IMHO very bad and half-finished control, I recommend staying away from it. Normal `ListBox` + `DataTemplateSelector` can do the grouping and scrolling with just a bit of extra work, it's well worth getting rid of LLC's constrains.

Comment: @Agent_L, could you elaborate on what is half-finished about the LLC, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you refer to talks about the `ListBox` and you're asking about the `LongListSelector`. Unfortunately their internals are very different and the approach used on the ListBox can't be used for the LLS.

The [DataBoundListBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/databoundlistbox.aspx) in the [control collection from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) includes this functionality. It is a popular control and used in lots of apps. That's probably what you've seen.
Part of the reason for its popularity is that it's included in the [Premium Developer Program from Nokia](https://developer.nokia.com/Developer_Programs/Lumia_developer_program.xhtml).

If you really want to customize the LLS to add this functionality, you'll need to look at handing the manipulation and mouse events to alter the `ListHeader` appropriately. This is a non-trivial task and your time and money will probably be much better spent with the Telerik controls available through the Nokia program. Plus there are other benefits from the program too.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Does that DataBoundListBox support grouping? Because grouping is the reason I decided use LLS in a first place.

Comment: The RadDataBoundListBox supports grouping and sorting.